# When creating a SSL certificate should the common name be the domain name or IP address?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I run this command to create a certificate:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
```

It asks me to fill information as shown below:

- Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:US
- State or Province Name (full
  name) [Some-State]:New York
- Locality Name (eg, city) []:New York City
- Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:Test, Inc.
- Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:Ministry of Water Slides
- Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []: **should this be domain name or IP address?**
- Email Address []:admin@your_domain.com

Answer (score 1):

The common name of a server certificate is irrelevant for modern TLS stacks. Instead the Subject Alternative Names must be used. CN is considered obsolete and major browsers (Google Chrome and related) will not even consider what's inside the CN.

In the SAN then the name need to be given which is used to access the site. This means if the URL is `https://domain/` then `domain` must be used as SAN type DNSName. If the URL instead is `https://ip/` then `ip` must be used with SAN type IPAddr. For domains wildcards can be used too, but only a single wildcard in the leftmost label.

Comment: The command that I have mentioned in my questions doesn't give me any option to enter the `Subject Alternative Names`

Comment: @variable: A [simple search](https://www.google.com/search?q=openssl+create+self+signed+certificate+with+san) will give you many posts on how to do this, for example https://gist.github.com/KeithYeh/bb07cadd23645a6a62509b1ec8986bbc